Shadcn/ui CommandDialog How can the ui not be vertically centered without changing the original code?
I am using nextjs + shadcn/ui
The current situation is that the keyboard pops up when the CommandDialog is opened on the phone, but the CommandDialog is always centered and blocked by the keyboard. I tried to simply add className or style but failed. It seems that the component does not accept these attributes.
I'd like to simply remove something like top-[50%] data-[state=open]:slide-in-from-top-[48%] so that it uses properties like top-0, how can i do this?
